# Share your knowledge, Q&A-style link is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

When you go to **Ask Question**, next to **Answer your own question** there is a link **share your knowledge Q&A-style**, it takes you to https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ but the page page doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: This seems more fit for [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) as this issue seems to be present in several of the sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @CoolGuy you are right, if any moderator could move the question that would be nice

Comment: There seems to be several [missing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264243/broken-blog-link-on-pages-with-lists-of-moderators) [links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264247/attribution-required-link-to-a-blog-post-on-the-bottom-of-every-page-is-giving)...

Comment: All blog posts before April 2014 are gone.

Comment: Now the link in this question works. Probably a temporary problem.

Comment: Mmm, actually it looks like it is [a problem with partial builds of the blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262079/238706).

Comment: A complete build was run, the links are back.