# Should Meta questions tagged with status-completed be closed as "not reproducible"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, meta, closed-questions

I admit, it's a slow news day.

*[Capitalize "possible duplicate of <x>" properly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307037/capitalize-possible-duplicate-of-x-properly)* recently went through the typical "feature-request" → "staff response" → "[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)" phase. Then something mildly interesting happened: the question [was closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/307037/revisions) as "not-reproducible" (it's since been re-opened).

Apparently, there is a precedent for this, both from a while ago and recently:

- [Remove [handling]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258176/remove-handling)
- [Share your knowledge, Q&A-style link is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303478/share-your-knowledge-qa-style-link-is-broken) (this has been re-opened since I asked this question)

But it's clearly not the norm:

- Unclosed [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) questions: [744](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[status-completed]+closed%3Ano)
- Closed [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) questions (not including duplicates): [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[status-completed]+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano)

Is it appropriate to close such questions as being not reproducible once they're fixed? Do such questions warrant any responses or discussion after they've been implemented?

Alternatively, should a moderator or staff member tagging a question with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) cause an automatic closing of the question (admittedly more appropriate as a feature-request, if it's supported, than a discussion question)?

What are the community's thoughts on this?

Comment: This question should be posted in meta.meta.stackoverflow

Comment: @AnderBiguri beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to close such questions as being not reproducible once they're fixed?

Usually, no. It just ends up being confusing to folks who report (or are thinking about reporting) problems, not to mention folks who notice that something has changed and go to find out why...

There are exceptions though: sometimes folks will report bugs or make feature-requests against features that, later on, are *replaced or removed entirely*; even though the bug was fixed / feature was implemented, neither the fix nor the feature it pertains to exist anymore - it's literally a fix that *can't be reproduced!*

Some of these are *still* worth preserving for the historical record and/or discussion that surrounded them... But many are just a source of noise or confusion, and should be removed entirely - and closing is the first step to achieving that.

Comment: I agree. _Technically_, _"Can't be reproduced"_ is correct, but it can be confusing for future readers.